# Principal Curvatures of axisymmetric function

Tags: curvature

I have an axisymmetric function ( z = f(r) with r being the radius ) describing how a specific material is shaped under an applied force, a somewhat complicated function implemented in Mathematica. Now I need to calculate the two principal curvatures, and I'm quite at a loss as to how I should proceed.

Answers which can be easily implemented in Mathematica is much appreciated.
Many thanks in advance!